# Crash while expanding tableviewcell after search

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a tableview which has tableviewcells like so...[image]

On the click of this tableview cell, it expands to show some more buttons like so..

[image]

But if I make a search in the searchbar above and after I get the results, when I tap on the tableviewcell, it crashes showing some error message like

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (34) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update...

What could be the reason..?

Also, this is the code when the cell is tapped..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProductListTableViewCell

            else { return }


        switch cell.isExpanded

        {

        case true:

            self.expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)

        case false:

            self.expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)

        }


        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded

        tableview.beginUpdates()
        tableview.endUpdates()
    }
```

**EDIT 1** : This is the code for `numberOfRowsInSection`...

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if noSearchChar1 == true { 
            return filtered.count
        }

        if filtered.count == 0 && self.appDelegate.searchBarTapFlag == true {
            //            searchActive = false
            if deleteBtnTapped == true {

                return filtered.count
            }
            return newProdDetails.count

        }
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
        return newProdDetails.count
}
```

**EDIT 2:** This is the code where the `filtered` array gets some data...

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText != "" {
        charInSearchBar = true

        //filter the results
        searchActive = true

        filtered = self.newProdDetails.filter({( data : NewProduct) -> Bool in
            return (data.name!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        }) //'filtered' array gets data here.

        if(filtered.count == 0){

            noSearchChar1 = true //this flag is to prevent no data showing on click of back btn.
            noSearchChar = true


        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        tableview.reloadData() //tableview is reloaded
    } else {
            noSearchChar1 = false
            searchActive = false
            self.tableview.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your `numberOfRowsInSection` code, but as the error message says, the number of rows returned by this method is inconsistent with the changes you have made (or not made) to the tableview

Comment: .@ Paulw11 Have edited the question and added the code for `numberOfRowsInSection`...

Comment: What error it displays ?

Comment: You can't track the expanded state of a cell in the `ProductListTableViewCell` instance since cells will be reused.

Comment: ok @Paulw11 so what can be done so that the required cells can be expanded after search...?

Comment: You need to track expanded state in some other data structure such as a set.  It looks like your crash is unrelated to the selection, but is triggered by the begin/end updates in the selection code.  I suspect (but the code isn't shown) that you are switching between the filtered/unfiltered data without calling `reloadData` - If the tableview sees a change in the number of rows without you calling the appropriate insert/delete/reload functions to explain the change you get a crash.

Comment: No, it is nothing to do with the code shown.  Somewhere else you are putting data into `filtered` which causes `numberOfRowsInSection` to return a different number of rows.  When you call begin/end updates it causes the tableview to call `numberOfRowsInSection` where it gets an unexpected result; the number of rows has changed but you didn't call insert/delete or reload data.  Once you put data in `filtered` you need to call `reloadData`

Comment: ok. Thanks for the explanation @Paulw11. Let me try what you suggested...

Answer (score 0):

You get a crash because you are changing the number of rows returned by `numberOfRowsInSection:` but you haven't given the table view any reason to expect the number of rows to change.

Somewhere (in code not shown) you put data into `filtered`, which causes `numberOfRowsInSection:` to return `filtered.count` instead of `newProdDetails.count`.  This doesn't cause an immediate crash, because the tableview doesn't call `numberOfRowsInSection:` at that point.

When you select a row and call `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` the tableview does call `numberOfRowsInSection:` and you then get the crash because the number of rows has changed but the tableview doesn't expect the change.

When you switch between the filtered data and the unfiltered data (or make a change in the filtered results) you need to call `reloadData`.

Also, you can't store the `isExpanded` value in the cell, since cell objects will be reused.  You need to store it in your data model somewhere.  Storing the `indexPath` won't work since the rows numbers will change as you filter the data.

Comment: Ok @Paulw11. But in this case I'm not switching between filtered data and unfiltered data because when I make a search I get some data in my `filtered` array. Then without switching to unfiltered data , I'm clicking on the row (to call `didSelectRow`). Also, I'm reloading the tableview after having data in `filtered`. I have also edited the question and added the code where the `filtered` array is filled...

Comment: Your code seems to be quite a bit more complicated than I would expect, but you can see that essentially in some cases you return `filtered.count` otherwise you return `newProdDetails.count`; somehow you are switching between returning these two values without a call to `reloadData`; The full text of the crash message will explain; You are returning, say 1, from `numberOfRowsInSection` when the tableview expects you to return 34.

Comment: I would define `filtered` as an optional and then when there is no search results, `filtered` is `nil`, otherwise it has some value (which may be an empty array if nothing matched the filter).  Then your `numberOfRowsInSection` is just `return self.filtered?.count ?? self.newProdDetails.count`

Comment: ok @Paulw11...so how can I tell the didSelectRow when I'm having filtered data and when I'm having data that isn't filtered..?

Comment: The issue has been fixed @Paulw11. Just had to give the bool value as `searchActive = true` in didSelectRow so that it would specify in the `cellForRow` that the filtered array has to be accessed..

Answer (score -1):

In your switch statement in `didSelectRowAt`, you didnt insert again after you remove the old cell, so the number of cells is not the same.

When you call beginUpdates, compiler expect actions like insertion / deletion of the row, but in your case, you didnt and then just endUpdates, which compiler will treat as no updates and hence your code delete or insert above will trigger the error "number of rows not equal"

Simply put the switch statement inside

```
   tableview.beginUpdates()
   switch cell.isExpanded

    {

    case true:

        self.expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)

    case false:

        self.expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)

    }

    tableview.endUpdates()
```

should work

> If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid.
>   fyi: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates